# How do I write a multi row single column (or multiple columns) equation?

Tags: equations, math-operators

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}

\nabla_Q N_I = \{{N_{I,1}} \\ {N_{I,2}} \\ {N_{I,3}}\} = J_{e}^{-T}\{N_{I,\xi} \\ N_{I,\eta} \\ N_{I,\zeta}\}

\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I want the data on the right side of the equation to be divided in 3 rows within curly braces. How can I do it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add an approximate representation of what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: For the curly braces in the left matrix to appear, use `\{`...`\}` instead of  `{`...`}`. Use the same approach for them to appear on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `amsmath` package already provides the needed tools: `Bmatrix` for the multiline matrix with curly braces and `bmatrix` for the matrix with square brackets.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Here is an equation
\begin{equation}
\nabla_Q N_I = 
\begin{Bmatrix}
  N_{I,1} \\
  N_{I,2} \\
  N_{I,3}
\end{Bmatrix} = 
J_{e}^{-T}
\begin{Bmatrix}
  N_{I,\xi} \\
  N_{I,\eta} \\
  N_{I,\zeta}
\end{Bmatrix},
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation*}
N_{I}=
\begin{bmatrix}
X_{1,\xi} & X_{1,\eta} & X_{1,\zeta} \\
X_{2,\xi} & X_{2,\eta} & X_{2,\zeta} \\
X_{3,\xi} & X_{3,\eta} & X_{3,\zeta}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way. I define an `lrcases` and a `dlrcases` environment, analogous to the `(d)cases` and `(d)rcases` environments from `mathtools`. The code is borrowed from @Gonzalo Medina:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools, bm}

\makeatletter
\newcases{dlrcases}{\quad}{%
  $\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{\lbrace}{\rbrace}
\newcases{lrcases}{\quad}{%
  $\m@th{##}$\hfil}{{##}\hfil}{\lbrace}{\rbrace}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \nabla_Q N_I =
  \begin{dlrcases}
    N_{I,1} \\ N_{I,2} \\ N_{I,3}
  \end{dlrcases}
  =\bm J_{e}^{-T} \begin{dlrcases}
  N_{I,\xi} \\ N_{I,\eta} \\ N_{I,\zeta}
  \end{dlrcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `Bmatrix` is already there.