# write equation with more than one curly brace

Tags: equations, braces

I was trying to write the equation, but did not get enough hints in tex.stackexchange.com

[image]

Comment: Note to @strawhat - please add code showing how far you've gotten (a complete compilable document). Note to answerers. This display might be easier to read if the entries on the right and the left of the equal signs were horizontally aligned.

Comment: take a look at the "matrices" section of the `amsmath` documentation (`texdoc amsmath`).  and do provide the code for what you've tried already.  (finally, welcome to tex.sx.)

Comment: Look at my answer to this [similar question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245254/how-do-i-write-a-multi-row-single-column-or-multiple-columns-equation/245262#245262). Iused @Gonzalo Medina's code to define `lrcases` and `dlrcases` environments.

Answer (score 3):

This should get you started :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{Bmatrix}
\varepsilon^{m}_{xx} \\
\varepsilon^{m}_{yy} \\
\gamma^{m}_{xy}
\end{Bmatrix}
=
\begin{Bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \\
\end{Bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution. I've modified `arraystrech` slightly to provide more space around the differentials, they kinda box into each other. I also made two small macro's for the greeks, they felt kinda repetative.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\myeps[2]{\varepsilon^{#1}_{#2}}
\newcommand\mygam[2]{\gamma^{#1}_{#2}}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{Bmatrix}
    \myeps{m}{xx} \\
    \myeps{m}{xx} \\
    \mygam{m}{xy}
  \end{Bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{Bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \\
    \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \\
    \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
  \end{Bmatrix}
  ;
  \begin{Bmatrix}
    \myeps{f}{xx} \\
    \myeps{f}{yy} \\
    \mygam{f}{xy}
  \end{Bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{Bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} \\
    \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y} \\
    \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}
  \end{Bmatrix}
\end{equation}
%
and the next
%
\begin{equation}
  \begin{Bmatrix}
    \mygam{(0)}{xy} \\
    \mygam{(0)}{xy}
  \end{Bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{Bmatrix}
    \theta_x - \frac{\partial w_0}{\partial x} \\
    \theta_y - \frac{\partial w_0}{\partial y}
  \end{Bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]